# Error when I run $ mongo with $mongod

Tags: mongodb, shell, unix, path, symlink

### EDIT: I found the answer and posted it below.

Trying to run mongo but have some problems.

What I've done after created a symlink "sudo ln s" from bin/mongo(d) to usr/local/bin/mongo(d):

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<user>/downloads/mongodb/bin

$ sudo ln -s ~/downloads/mongodb/bin/mongod /usr/local/bin/mongod

$ sudo ln -s ~/downloads/mongodb/bin/mongod /usr/local/bin/mongo
```

Now when I run:

```
$ mongo --version
```

Outputs:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.10
```

When I run:

```
$ mongod --dbpath ~/data/db/
```

It runs the MongoDB core server and waiting for connections on port 27017

While running the server, I open up a new tab in terminal. I run:

```
$ mongo
```

and get this message while it runs and exits.

```
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

How do I make the mongo shell run?

### **Answer:**

I created the wrong symlink with ln -s. I linked mongod to both mongo and mongod. Unlinked both and linked them correctly. Then I did: export PATH=/bin:$PATH

Comment: If you are getting that output when you run `mongo` then you actually symlinked to `mongod` since that is the database instance output and not that from the shell.

Comment: Ran: unlink /usr/local/bin/mongo. Then I ran: $ sudo ln -s ~/downloads/mongodb/bin/mongo /usr/local/bin/mongo. Now it shows: -bash: /usr/local/bin/mongo: no such file or directory

Comment: Instead of editing your question and including the answer in your question, you should **answer** your own question.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to this problem I found.

First mkdir /data/db in root directory:

```
$ sudo bash

$ mkdir -p /data/db/

$ chmod 777 /data
$ chmod 777 /data/db
```

Then simply cd to BIN directory of your MongoDB download then do:

```
$ sudo bash

$ cp * /usr/local/bin
```

Now you can run $ mongod and $ mongo